# Select all customers who do not hold any products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

```
customer_ID product_id product_returned_date
1           a          12/12/2018
1           b          NULL
2           a          NULL
3           b          24/02/2018
2           c          NULL
1           c          23/05/2017
```

In the above scenario, there are three customers with ID 1,2,3. There are three products with ID a,b,c. The return date specifies the date on which a product was returned. If it is NULL, the product was not returned. I would like to query all the customer_IDs who do not hold ANY products at all.

Customer `1` currently holds products `b` as they have returned `a` and `c`.

Customer `2` currently holds product `a` and `c`.

Customer `3` has returned product `b` and hence doesn't currently hold any products.

Hence, I want to return customer 3.

---

Attempt: 
`select customer_ID from table where product_returned_date is not null`

However, this doesn't ensure that the customer isn't holding any products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should select all customer_ID's from the table where a row with a null return date does not exist (all products returned).

```
SELECT
    a.customer_ID
FROM
    table a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            customer_ID
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            customer_ID = a.Customer_ID
            AND
            product_returned_date IS NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want customers all of whose products have a return date.  You can do this using aggregation:

```
select customer_id
from t
group by customer_id
having count(*) = count(product_returned_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

with this scenario

```
3           b          24/02/2018
3           b          24/02/2018
```

i'm thinking using this query.

```
select customer_ID from tableA
group by customer_ID, product_id  
having count(distinct customer_ID, product_ID) = 1;
```